# Applying "String matching to estimate similarity" to data frame

Tags: r, string, text-mining, text-analysis

[String matching to estimate similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936951/string-matching-to-estimate-similarity)

The above code is exactly what I am looking for, except I cannot seem to figure out how to compare the strings between columns (the "correct" answer and "given" answer) in a data frame and then storing the output from sim.per as a new column ("similarity") in that same data frame. I have tried .e.g,

```
df$similarity <- sim.per(df$answer, df$given) 

df$similarity <- mapply(sim.per, df$answer, df$given)
```

The latter also results in an error when the row is empty, which is acceptable in my dataset and should be calculated as 0 instead.

```
Error in str2[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Expected output should be:

```
    answer                   given                              similarity
1   Best way to waste money  Instrument to waste money and time 0.6
2   Roy travels to Africa    He is in Africa                    0.25
3   I go to work                                                0
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Subset of the data:

```
df <- structure(list(trial = 1:10, answer = structure(c(9L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("Best way to waste money", "He ran out of money, so he had to stop playing poker", "I go to work", "Lets all be unique together until we realise we are all the same", "Roy travels to Africa", "She borrowed the book from him many years ago and did not returned it yet", "She did her best to help him", "Students did not cheat on the test, for it was not the right thing to do", "The stranger officiates the meal", "We have a lot of rain in June"), class = "factor"), given = structure(c(10L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("", "He is in Africa Roy", "He lost money because he had played poker", "Instrument to waste money and time", "It was raining in June", "People are unique until they try to fit in", "She borrowed the book from the library and forgot to return it", "She did her very best to help him out", "Students know not to cheat", "The guests ate the meal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: can please provide a sample subset of the data you are using? Please use use dput(sample_data) and then copy paste the result from the console

Comment: I've edited the post to include a sample of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using `tidyverse` syntax to avoid manual loops and make things a bit more concise and probably faster. In particular, the format step is vectorised so only the score calculation requires iteration.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(trial = 1:10, answer = structure(c(9L, 2L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("Best way to waste money", "He ran out of money, so he had to stop playing poker", "I go to work", "Lets all be unique together until we realise we are all the same", "Roy travels to Africa", "She borrowed the book from him many years ago and did not returned it yet", "She did her best to help him", "Students did not cheat on the test, for it was not the right thing to do", "The stranger officiates the meal", "We have a lot of rain in June"), class = "factor"), given = structure(c(10L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("", "He is in Africa Roy", "He lost money because he had played poker", "Instrument to waste money and time", "It was raining in June", "People are unique until they try to fit in", "She borrowed the book from the library and forgot to return it", "She did her very best to help him out", "Students know not to cheat", "The guests ate the meal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

format_str <- function(string) {
  string %>%
    str_to_lower %>%
    str_remove_all("[:punct:]") %>%
    str_squish %>%
    str_split(" ")
}

df %>%
  mutate(
    similarity = map2_dbl(
      .x = format_str(answer),
      .y = format_str(given),
      .f = ~ length(intersect(.x, .y)) / length(.x)
    )
  ) %>%
  as_tibble
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    trial answer                        given                    similarity
#>    <int> <fct>                         <fct>                         <dbl>
#>  1     1 The stranger officiates the ~ The guests ate the meal       0.4  
#>  2     2 He ran out of money, so he h~ He lost money because h~      0.333
#>  3     3 Lets all be unique together ~ People are unique until~      0.231
#>  4     4 She did her best to help him  She did her very best t~      1    
#>  5     5 Best way to waste money       Instrument to waste mon~      0.6  
#>  6     6 Roy travels to Africa         He is in Africa Roy           0.5  
#>  7     7 I go to work                  ""                            0    
#>  8     8 She borrowed the book from h~ She borrowed the book f~      0.467
#>  9     9 Students did not cheat on th~ Students know not to ch~      0.25 
#> 10    10 We have a lot of rain in June It was raining in June        0.25
```

Created on 2018-08-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Just an update, I tried this code with my larger data set and it doesn’t seem to work at well as the for loop

Comment: I am not getting the correct similarity calculation. I've compared the similarity between the two methods (and even with manually coding the sentences) and this code is consistently wrong in it's calculation. For instance, a sentence that should be getting a score of 1 (or 100% matches) is being calculated as 0.9285714. The difference ranges anywhere from -10 or 15% difference compared to the other code

Comment: Can you give some examples of incorrect sentences? This is currently giving the same results as the other answer with your example data.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help. It was also the leading, trailing and middle white space that was creating the inconsistency. I added the code the line, str_squish, and that fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is by using a for lop and going through each row in the dataframe to calculate the similarity percent using the functions from the other thread.

```
df <- structure(list(trial = 1:10, answer = structure(c(9L, 2L, 4L, 
                                                        7L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L), .Label = c("Best way to waste money", 
                                                                                                 "He ran out of money, so he had to stop playing poker", "I go to work", 
                                                                                                 "Lets all be unique together until we realise we are all the same", 
                                                                                                 "Roy travels to Africa", "She borrowed the book from him many years ago and did not returned it yet", 
                                                                                                 "She did her best to help him", "Students did not cheat on the test, for it was not the right thing to do", 
                                                                                                 "The stranger officiates the meal", "We have a lot of rain in June"
                                                        ), class = "factor"), given = structure(c(10L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 
                                                                                                  2L, 1L, 7L, 9L, 5L), .Label = c("", "He is in Africa Roy", "He lost money because he had played poker", 
                                                                                                                                  "Instrument to waste money and time", "It was raining in June", 
                                                                                                                                  "People are unique until they try to fit in", "She borrowed the book from the library and forgot to return it", 
                                                                                                                                  "She did her very best to help him out", "Students know not to cheat", 
                                                                                                                                  "The guests ate the meal"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      -10L))

format <- function(string1){ #removing the information from the string which presumably isn't important (punctuation, capital letters. then splitting all the words into separate strings)
  lower <- tolower(string1)
  no.punct <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", lower)
  split <- strsplit(no.punct, split=" ")
  return(split)
}

sim.per <- function(str1, str2, ...){#how similar is string 1 to string 2. NOTE: the order is important, ie. sim.per(b,c) is different from sim.per(c,b)
  sim <- length(intersect(str1[[1]], str2[[1]]))#intersect function counts the common strings
  total <- length(str1[[1]])
  per <- sim/total
  return(per)
}

df$similarity <- 0
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  if (!is.na(df$answer[i]) | !is.na(df$given[i])) {
    df$similarity[i] <- sim.per(format(df$answer[i]), format(df$given[i]))
  }
}

df
   trial                                                                    answer                                                          given similarity
1      1                                          The stranger officiates the meal                                        The guests ate the meal  0.4000000
2      2                      He ran out of money, so he had to stop playing poker                      He lost money because he had played poker  0.3333333
3      3          Lets all be unique together until we realise we are all the same                     People are unique until they try to fit in  0.2307692
4      4                                              She did her best to help him                          She did her very best to help him out  1.0000000
5      5                                                   Best way to waste money                             Instrument to waste money and time  0.6000000
6      6                                                     Roy travels to Africa                                            He is in Africa Roy  0.5000000
7      7                                                              I go to work                                                                 0.0000000
8      8 She borrowed the book from him many years ago and did not returned it yet She borrowed the book from the library and forgot to return it  0.4666667
9      9  Students did not cheat on the test, for it was not the right thing to do                                     Students know not to cheat  0.2500000
10    10                                             We have a lot of rain in June                                         It was raining in June  0.2500000
```

Comment: This code works for the first few rows and then the answer is 0 in the remaining ones. How can the coded be amended to fix this problem? I've added the sample data set that I ran with this code

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong sequence; see the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks! I’ve tried out the edited code with my larger data set (I have about 100 sentences from 30 participants = ~ 3000 data points) and for the most part, it’s pretty accurate but some of the calculations are still wrong (best guess, 15 - 20% of the data). It might not be from your code specifically, but maybe the original link.. Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing the data I have no good idea why some of the calculations are not working.  Can you post some of the cases where the calculation is wrong?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks! Some sentences had leading/trailing spaces (which only became obvious to me when I was structuring my sample cases using dput()).. I incorrectly assumed that the code used to remove all other punctuation would also remove whitespace